# VirtualBox for Mac: use WiFi on Windows 10 VM

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I configured my Windows 10 Education VM's networking as such

[image]

I also have to Cable Connected option checked. But when I log into the ghost system, WiFi isn't an option

[image]

It says ethernet Network 3 is connected, but it is not. (**Update**: now it says No Internet)

I also tried other configurations in [this thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=19305). Nothing worked. Any solutions for this problem?

---

Environment:
MacOS Siera
VirtualBox 5.1.14
Ghost system: Windows 10 v.1607 for x64 based system

Comment: When you share your Wireless network connection from the host, the guest OS doesn't get to manage and install the hardware, because it runs into a sandbox. It just gets access to the network thru a Bridged Connection, and windows gets to see it has available a network adapter, that it installs and uses to access the network. It doesn't care if it's an ethernet or wireless or any other thing, but gets to use the network as is

Comment: @fernando.reyes Thanks. If you can see this reply, I am connected to WiFi in my host machine. But I opened Microsoft Edge and enter google.com on the ghost machine, it says it cannot open. Also in the Network Settings, now the status becomes No Internet.

Comment: What is the IP address of the host and the guest OSs? I bet it's something about the DHCP

Comment: @fernando.reyes should the IPs be the same on both OSes?

Comment: @fernando.reyes they have different IPs. Should I change the VM's IP to match the host's IP?

Comment: No, do not set ANY 2 devices to have the same IP address in a network. I thought WiFi had to be NAT'd to a guest OS in VirtualBox, only a wired connection could be bridged.

Comment: I don't know about the Bridged restrictions for Wireless or Wired networks, but if you have it as bridged you must have a dynamic IP in your OS, if your guest has a static IP you need to use NAT

Comment: @fernando.reyes I tried NAT but it did not work. But now it works. Put it as the answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case of a Bridged Adapter only works when you have a dynamic IP, that looks to not be the case here.

If you are using a static IP, configure it as NAT and the network connection should work inside the guest OS as it work into the host OS.